# How to get a key from another table in a insert into... Values SQL statement?

Tags: sql, select, insert

I am not very experienced in SQL statements and I am trying to combine a couple of statements to have less traffic to the db.(and to make sure no other actions can happen inbetween)...

I have two tables:

Table: R_LOTS
a.o. 2 columns: PK_R_LOT and LOTCODE

Table: R_LOTTRACKING
Columns: FK_R_LOT,TIMESTAMP,FK_MAGLOCATIES

I use the statement:

```
INSERT INTO R_LOTTRACKING (FK_R_LOT,TIMESTAMP,FK_MAGLOCATIES) VALUES (?,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,?).
```

On the questionmarks I can fill in the values to send.

However, as you can imagine, I do not have the FK_R_LOT but I have the LOTCODE (of R_LOT).. Of course I can get the FK_R_LOT with a seperate `SELECT PK_R_LOT FROM R_LOT WHERE LOTCODE=?;`  but is there a way to combine these statements?

I have seen some examples but then all information seems to come from the R_LOT table but I could not find a combination of VALUES and SELECT.

Summary:

I know: LOTCODE and FK_MAGLOCATIES

How to combine the statements to insert the row:

```sql
INSERT INTO R_LOTTRACKING (FK_R_LOT,TIMESTAMP,FK_MAGLOCATIES) VALUES (?,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,?)

SELECT PK_R_LOT FROM R_LOT WHERE LOTCODE=?
```

Comment: Tag the RDBMS you are *really* using and **only** that RDBMS please.

Comment: If you *are* using SQL Server, inserting the value of `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` into your `TIMESTAMP` column doesn't make any sense; `timestamp` is a (deprecated) synonym for `rowversion` and is a `binary` value, *not* a date and time value.

Comment: @Larnu, sorry. I am a bit new here. and my was first denied for the tags... I am using the MSSQL server. The CURRENT_TIMESTAMP Is giving me the current date and time in my db. I can still change the name of this column but is there a real problem of using this?

Comment: Then, like I mentioned, the above seems wrong. You can't insert values into a `timestamp` column; SQL Server controls the value of the `rowversion`.

Comment: I will repair the timestamp column if necessary, but it is working.. But, if better , i will change that..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a subquery:

```
INSERT INTO R_LOTTRACKING ( FK_R_LOT, ... )
VALUES ( (SELECT PK_R_LOT FROM R_LOT WHERE LOTCODE = ?), ... );
```

or use an insert select:

```
INSERT INTO R_LOTTRACKING ( FK_R_LOT, ... )
SELECT PK_R_LOT, ... FROM R_LOT WHERE LOTCODE = ?;
```

Comment: wow, that  seems logical. Going to test. Great, thanks. I have still a following question about combining this insert Into statement with another UPDATE statement in another table.. Do I have to make a new question for that or cna I use this one?

Comment: Make this another request. `INSERT` plus `UPDATE` can be done with `MERGE` (https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15). Maybe this helps already?

Comment: I have seen that but I also did not manage to translate it to my situation. After testing the above, I will first try to understand the merge and otherwise post it here. thanks!

Comment: Okay. As to your original question: I've added an alternative that is just as good :-)

Comment: Hi Thorsten, I do not understand how I can include my values in the second statement. Ofcourse I can include lotcode with a WHERE statement but how to include the FK_MAGLOCATIES with the  questionmark ??  The first methode works perfectly... However, understanding how to do this with the second cna also be interesting to learn....

Comment: Ah, sorry, I didn't see that you need another foreign key there. (And I forgot the where clause.) Generally, though you can put everything in that select clause: `SELECT PK_R_LOT, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 123, 'hello', (select value from sometable where id = 789), ... FROM R_LOT WHERE LOTCODE = ?;`

Comment: aha, interesting. So you can just put values in the SELECT statement.....Thats a surprise to me... Thanks!! That makes all the examples I encountered more comprehensible....